# Postgres epoch from current_timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I've learned that epoch (UNIX timestamp) is a unique independent amount, so I am baffled by output I get from the following queries:

```
select  extract( epoch from current_timestamp::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'Asia/Tehran');
1588605420.89165


select  extract( epoch from current_timestamp::timestamp with timezone at time zone 'UTC');
1588589296.18219
```

which there is a deficit of 16200 (4 and a half hours). Why is that when it **explicitly** declares that current_timestamp is in a specific time zone. Should both epochs (UNIX timestamp) not map to the **same** amount of seconds?

what I don't get maybe better displayed on contrast with this small python code:

```
>>> import time
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime
>>> teh_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tehran')
>>> utc_tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')

>>> datetime.datetime.now(teh_tz)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 15, 31, 11, 14869, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tehran' +0430+4:30:00 DST>)
>>> datetime.datetime.now(utc_tz)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 11, 1, 16, 198437, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> datetime.datetime.now(teh_tz).timestamp()
1588590087.590199
>>> datetime.datetime.now(utc_tz).timestamp()
1588590091.901826
```

As it's seen, different time zones have differences in their current time but all map to the same amount of seconds (UNIX timestamp).
I guess I'm totally lost in here, please save me.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) of `extract` clearly states:

> For `timestamp with time zone` values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (can be negative); for `date` and `timestamp` values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 local time; for interval values, the total number of seconds in the interval

If you want to know how many seconds passed since Jan. 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 *in your time zone*, use

```
extract(epoch FROM localtimestamp)
```

The result of `AT TIME ZONE`, when applied to a `timestamp with time zone`, is always a `timestamp without time zone`.  `extract` will interpret such a time stamp **in your current time zone** (it does not know about the second argument you passed to `AT TIME ZONE`).

Your comment suggests that you want to get the (absolute) epoch at the beginning of the current day in your time zone. That would be

```
extract(epoch FROM date_trunc('day', current_timestamp))
```

Comment: Does it mean that in above queries for calculating seconds, the beginning of time points is same but the endings are different (which are provided in queries)?, I dont seem to get the point.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The beginning the same (midnight Jan 1 1970 in your time zone). The first end point is what the wall clock currently shows in Teheran, but interpreted in your current time zone. The second end point is what an UTC wall clock currently shows, again interpreted in your current time zone. What is the value you would like to get?

Comment: Since time stored as epoch in DB and I need to query them based on current_timestamp on my timezone (4 and half hours after UTC), I wanna map it (current_timestamp on my timezone) to the same epoch, UTC current_timestamp mapped to. I'm stuck.

Comment: Erm, I cannot understand that. What is the result you need?

Comment: Sorry for delay and thank you for attention you paid. What I am after is do a query to fetch number of users which their time is bigger or equal than beginning of current day (or beginning of yesterday ...) at my timezone (something like 2020-05-05 04:30:00). And since their time stored as epoch I try the following: **select count(*) from users where created_at >= extract( epoch from( date_trunc('day', current_timestamp)::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'Asia/Tehran' - interval '0' day) );**

Comment: I have added the desired expression to the answer. This is a good example why it is better to store proper timestamps than seconds since the epoch - your SQL would become simpler and more readable.

Comment: @aliebrahimi "*since their time stored as epoch*" - which is the root cause of your problem. You should have used `timestamptz` for that. Storing an epoch is almost always the wrong choice in a database (and your current problem is a direct result of that decision). See e.g. here https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/